# D3 change map colors on select from dropdown

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am new to d3js and I need some help for my project. I want to my map to change color on dropdown change. I have added two maps in my code, default would be data/world-map.json, and I want to change to data/2000.json when 2000 is selected from dropdown menu. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project</title>
    <style>
      .country {
        stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    }
    .country:hover{
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.text{
  font-size:10px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
#container {
  margin:10px 10%;
  border:2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #F0F8FF;
}
.hidden { 
  display: none; 
}
div.tooltip {
  color: #222; 
  background: #fff; 
  padding: .5em; 
  text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  position: absolute;
}
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #bbb;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.equator {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1 align="center">FIFA PLAYER OF THE YEAR 2000 - 2010</h1>

  <select id="select_button" name="select_button">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select year</option>
    <option value="1">2000.</option>
    <option value="2">2001.</option>
    <option value="3">2002.</option>
    <option value="4">2003.</option>
    <option value="5">2004.</option>
    <option value="6">2005.</option>
    <option value="7">2006.</option>
    <option value="8">2007.</option>
    <option value="9">2008.</option>
    <option value="10">2009.</option>
    <option value="11">2010.</option>
  </select>
  <div id="container"></div>

<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);


var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;



var currentKey = '0';
d3.select('#select_button').on('change', function(a) {
  currentKey = d3.select(this).property('value');
  draw(topo);
});



var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);

function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([(width/2), (height/2)])
    .scale( width / 2 / Math.PI);

  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .on("click", click)
      .append("g");

  g = svg.append("g");

}

d3.json("data/world-map.json", function(error, world) {

  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);

});

d3.json("data/2000.json", function(error, world) {

  var countries2 = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  topo = countries2;
  draw(topo);

});



d3.selectAll("path").remove();

function draw(topo) {

/*  svg.append("path")
     .datum(graticule)
     .attr("class", "graticule")
     .attr("d", path);


  g.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 0], [-90, 0], [0, 0], [90, 0], [180, 0]]})
   .attr("class", "equator")
   .attr("d", path);
*/

  var country = g.selectAll(".country").data(topo);

  country.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
      .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return d.properties.color; });

  //offsets for tooltips
  var offsetL = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft+20;
  var offsetT = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop+10;

  //tooltips
  country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {

      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

      tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name);

      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      });

/*
  //EXAMPLE: adding some capitals from external CSV file
  d3.csv("data/country-capitals.csv", function(err, capitals) {

    capitals.forEach(function(i){
      addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.CapitalName );
    });

  }); */

}


function redraw() {
  width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
  height = width / 2;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  setup(width,height);
  draw(topo);
}


function move() {

  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale; 
  zscale = s;
  var h = height/4;


  t[0] = Math.min(
    (width/height)  * (s - 1), 
    Math.max( width * (1 - s), t[0] )
  );

  t[1] = Math.min(
    h * (s - 1) + h * s, 
    Math.max(height  * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1])
  );

  zoom.translate(t);
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

  //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
  d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 0.5 / s);

}



var throttleTimer;
function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
    throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      redraw();
    }, 200);
}


//geo translation on mouse click in map
function click() {
  var latlon = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  console.log(latlon);
}


/*
//function to add points and text to the map (used in plotting capitals)
function addpoint(lat,lon,text) {

  var gpoint = g.append("g").attr("class", "gpoint");
  var x = projection([lat,lon])[0];
  var y = projection([lat,lon])[1];

  gpoint.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("class","point")
        .attr("r", 1.5);

  //conditional in case a point has no associated text
  if(text.length>0){

    gpoint.append("text")
          .attr("x", x+2)
          .attr("y", y+2)
          .attr("class","text")
          .text(text);
  }

}*/

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your sample does not work. Please post a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: Sorry, here is link to my code:  https://github.com/nenadicpetar/worldmap

Comment: Please, consider creating sandbox with your project, not just sharing the sources. It will significantly help other people to understand the issue.
You can use service like https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Sorry, but project use more than one js library, I can't put it in jsfiddle. That's why I shared link from Github.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I uploaded files on codesandbox, here is link: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nenadicpetar/visProject_codesandbox/tree/main/?file=/index.html